# Упаковка пачки прямоугольников в прямоугольник

Tags: алгоритм

Есть множество нормально ориентированных прямоугольников(параллельных оси X) `rect(w,h)` и большой прямоугольник `RECT(W,H)` в которой пакуются остальные(вращать их нельзя). Известно что `w<W h<H`. Существует ли какой-то точный способ заранее узнать влезут ли они все в большой прямоугольник, кроме способа при котором к ним вручную применяется известный алгоритмы упаковки(MAXRECTS, Гильотина) и затем просто смотрится свободное место(fill rate) в большом прямоугольнике.

Comment: Это слишком общая задача и такого алгоритма я думаю не найдется. Предметную область изложите.

Comment: Малые прямоугольники одинаковые?

Comment: @mikillskegg Нет они случайной ширины и высоты, но гарантированно меньше чем большой прямоугольник
@KaZaца Прдеметная область упаковка текстур. Есть папка с текстурами нужно разделить ее на под папки каждую из которой можно упаковать в прямоугольник 1024*1024. Чтобы не делать это вручную я пытаюсь придумать автоматический способ разбиения. Сам алгоритм упаковки у меня есть он работает нормально.

Comment: Раз есть алгоритм упаковки, думаю не составит труда его модифицировать, что бы он упаковал все ваши текстуры в квадраты 1024x1024 и тем самым разбить их на группы.

Comment: Да похоже я перемудрил, гораздо проще вручную в зависимости от того что нарисовано на текстуре разбить их на папки и после чего к каждой отдельно применить упаковку. Закрываю тред. Может кому-то еще окажется полезным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Описываемая вами задача - это вариация [`Bin Packing Problem,`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) для которой доказана ее `NP`-полнота.

> Соответственно, из теории алгоритмов напрямую следует, что задача о проверке того, поместятся ли ваши `{rect(w, h)}` внутрь `RECT(W, H)` — тоже `NP`-полная.

- Более того, применение эвристики в этом случае не гарантирует того, что ответ "да / нет" сохранится для исходной задачи, т.е. тот факт, что эвристический алгоритм не смог найти способа упаковки `{rect(w, h)}` в `RECT(W, H)` **не гарантирует** того, что этого способа не существует.

> В связи с этим, если говорить формально, единственный способ **точного** решения поставленной задачи - это взять какой-нибудь [**точный алгоритм**](http://www.alessiotrivella.altervista.org/pdf_files/proj_DTU.pdf) со сложностью `O(2^n)` и совершить проверку с его помощью.

- На практике (а вы наверняка пакуете текстуры / спрайты), думаю, можно каким-то образом прикрутить эвристический алгоритм(ы) и действительно смотреть на `fill rate` — все-таки мы имеем дело с `NP-`полнотой.

> - В плохом случае для конкретной эвристики вы получите неоптимальное разбиение, что, в общем-то, кажется мне не слишком критичным. Ну да, не получилось сэкономить 20 пикселей в файле с запакованными текстурами, ничего страшного.
> - **[Вот](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/)** еще один неплохой референс по теме, который мне удалось найти.

Comment: Проще говоря, самое точное решение - перебор всех возможных вариантов?

Comment: Да спасибо! Похоже вручную придется рассортировать их по папкам и затем к каждой папке применить MAXRECTS с BL эвристикой. 
Вот пример работы моего упаковщика. Благо ImageMagick быстро с этим расправляется и поддерживает 100 входных/выходных форматов картинок.
![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/V9PvMTp.png

Comment: @mikillskegg Ну если внимательно поискать, там наверняка есть какие-то алгоритмы с практическим ускорением по типу методов ветвей и границ, но да, раз задача `NP-`полная, то ее точное решение - это всегда перебор не быстрее, чем за `O(2^n).`